# Route.get() requires a callback function issue for API

Tags: node.js, express, http, routes, sequelize.js

I am trying to create an API for a project I have.

I came across this error and I was not sure what to do.

```
throw new Error(msg);
    ^

Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.<computed> [as get] (C:\Users\dunka\Documents\GitHub\weatherapp\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202:15)
    at Function.proto.<computed> [as get] (C:\Users\dunka\Documents\GitHub\weatherapp\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:510:19)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\dunka\Documents\GitHub\weatherapp\server\app\routes\weather.routes.js:13:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dunka\Documents\GitHub\weatherapp\server\server.js:24:39)
```

I believe that it has something to do with my lookup route but I am not sure. I will attach some code samples.

weather.routes.js

```
module.exports = app => {
    const weather = require("../controllers/weather.controllers.js");
  
    var router = require("express").Router();
  
    // Create a new Tutorial
    router.post("/lookup", weather.check);
  
    // Retrieve all weather
    router.get("/", weather.findAll);
  
    app.use('/api/weather', router);
  };
```

Data.js

```
import http from "../http-common";

class WeatherService {
  getAll() {
    return http.get("/weather");
  }

  get(id) {
    return http.get(`/weather/${id}`);
  }

  create(data) {
    return http.post("/weather", data);
  }

  check(data) {
    return http.post("/lookup", data)
  }
  
  update(id, data) {
    return http.put(`/weather/${id}`, data);
  }

  delete(id) {
    return http.delete(`/weather/${id}`);
  }

  deleteAll() {
    return http.delete(`/weather`);
  }

  findByTitle(title) {
    return http.get(`/weather?title=${title}`);
  }
}

export default new WeatherService();
```

weather.controllers.js

```
const db = require("../models");
const Weather = db.weather;
const Op = db.Sequelize.Op;
var functions = require('./functions');


//Check Weather

exports.check = (req, res) => {
    let city = req.body.city.toLowerCase();
    let values = functions.getData(city);

    WebAuthnAssertion.

    res.send(values);
    console.log(`It's ${values[0]} degrees in ${values[1]}!`);
};



// Find all published Tutorials
exports.findAllPublished = (req, res) => {
  
};
```

I am following this tutorial:

https://bezkoder.com/node-js-express-sequelize-mysql/

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

console.log(weather) returns

```
{
  create: [Function],
  check: [Function],
  findOne: [Function],
  update: [Function],
  delete: [Function],
  deleteAll: [Function]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not exporting a `findAll` middleware from your controller. Either rename `findAllPublished` in your controller to:

```
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
  // impl here
};
```

or set the router up using:

```
router.get("/", weather.findAllPublished);
```

Comment: no change. I already had that I just took it out for simplicity sake. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(weather)` after requiring it to debug this?

Comment: Well, there you have it :) `findAllPublished` is not exported. Double check your `weather.controllers.js` file for the exports, e.g. `findOne` seems to be exported correctly, so you could just adapt this for `findAllPublished`.